# SQL FUNCTION - one alias in SELECT AND WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I want to insert to NewTable some id(found by calledMethod) from table 'inserted' when this id actually it's not in this table(NewTable)
Actually i'm using this method (calledMethod)twice. How to reduce this using for example alias?

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
    ON Table
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NewTable
    (
        FirstId
        SecondId
    )
    SELECT 
        I.ID
        CalledMethod(I.Name) 
    FROM INSERTED I
    WHERE CalledMethod(I.Name)
    NOT IN (SELECT SecondId FROM NewTable)
END
GO
```

The second problem occures when I want insert two rows at the same time.

```
Insert Into Table
(
Name
)
Values
('ro'),('ro-RO')
```

In this situation, the method returns the same index and both will be added. How to resolve this problem.

In this situation, the method returns the same index

This is example of calledMethod

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalledMethod
(   
     @internalName nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS int
AS

  BEGIN
     return  case 
         when @internalName Like 'ro%'  then 6
         when @internalName Like 'sk%'  then 7
         when @internalName Like 'bg%'  then 9
          end 
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
    ON Table
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NewTable
    (
        FirstId
        SecondId
    )
    SELECT 
        min(I.ID),
        x.called
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT CalledMethod(I.Name) called) x
    WHERE 
      x.called NOT IN (SELECT SecondId FROM NewTable)
    GROUP BY x.called
END
```

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you very much.